# Problem with setting a context state while refreshing a page

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I have set up a context to store state of sidebar (collapsed/uncollapsed).
I have initialized it as such:

```js
const [isSidebarCollapsed, setIsSidebarCollapsed] = useState<boolean>(false);
```

I have used this context in a particular where on navigating to "Details" page the side must collapse.
Below is the code I have used to bring it in effect:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (!isSidebarCollapsed) {
    setIsSidebarCollapsed(true);
  }
}, [])
```

Everything behaves as expected when I navigate to "Details" page, but when I refresh the "Details" page the sidebar is set to default "false"?

I do not understand this behaviour. The behaviour I expected was for the sidebar to collapse on refresh as it was collapsing when I navigate to that page from any other page.

Comment: Can you create a code sandbox?

Answer (score 1):

When you refresh the page, the page is reloaded. When the page is reloaded, the React app is completely remounted. All state is the default initial state upon mounting. React state resides only in memory, if you would like state to persist through page reloads then you'll need to persist and initialize it from somewhere more longterm, e.g. localStorage.

Example:

```js
// Lazy initialize from localStorage
const [isSidebarCollapsed, setIsSidebarCollapsed] = useState<boolean>(() => {
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("isSidebarCollapsed")) ?? false;
});

// Persist isSidebarCollapsed state updates to localStorage
useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem("isSidebarCollapsed", JSON.stringify(isSidebarCollapsed));
}, [isSidebarCollapsed]);
```

Though it seems you ***want*** the sidebar to be collapsed when the component mounts, so you may actually want to use `true` as the default initial state value and forego the mounting `useEffect` hook to set it true.

```js
const [isSidebarCollapsed, setIsSidebarCollapsed] = useState<boolean>(true);
```

Comment: Understood.

Instead of initializing it in the local storage, I tried the below method which seems to work:

useEffect(() => {
    const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
        if (!isSidebarCollapsed) {
            setIsSidebarCollapsed(true);
        }
    }, 1);

    return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId);

Would this be a good approach?

Comment: @itsDespair1000 No, that now seems a bit convoluted. The lazy initialization isn't initializing the value in localStorage, it's taking any previously persisted value ***or*** returning the default/fallback value as the initial state. It's the `useEffect` hook that sets any values into localStorage. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: @itsDespair1000 Welcome, glad to help. Has this answer sufficiently addressed/resolved your question/issue?